# Specify display style to use with the growlnotify command-line utility

Tags: command-line, growl

Is there any way to change what display style is used with the `growlnotify` command line utility? I don't want to change the default one, just the one that is used for that instance of the command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`man growlnotify` does not allow an option, and `growlnotify --help` doesn't mention anything either. Which makes sense, because the issuing software does not control the style, *you are* -- via System Preferences!

But the `growlnotify` entry there *only has a single notification type `Command-Line Growl Notification`* (and not e.g. one notification type per priority). Therefore **I don't think it's possible**.

---

You can, however, create an AppleScript application/script that uses the Growl API to issue different types of notifications, based on some parameter. [Growl documentation on how to access it via AppleScript](http://growl.info/documentation/applescript-support.php).

Here's a sample script for AppleScript Editor:

```
on run argv
    tell application "GrowlHelperApp"
        set the allNotificationsList to ¬
            {"1", "2"}
        set the enabledNotificationsList to ¬
            {"1", "2"}
        register as application ¬
            "My Growl Notification App" all notifications allNotificationsList ¬
            default notifications enabledNotificationsList ¬
            icon of application "Script Editor"

        notify with name ¬
            (item 1 of argv) title ¬
            (item 2 of argv) description ¬
            (item 3 of argv) application name "My Growl Notification App"
    end tell
end run
```

"1" and "2" are the names of the supported notification types. Run this script like this:

```
osascript growlstyle.scpt 2 Hello\ World This\ is\ the\ text
```

Parameters are (in order) notification type name, title, and description.

[image]

After running it once, you can configure the display settings for the notification types in System Preferences.

[image]

Comment: You can, of course, use any name you like for your notifications. Since you probably want to specify them on the command line, I used single-character names.